# Alternative notation for intersection and union

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I was helping a friend recently with some math homework when I came across the following notations for intersection and union respectively:

$$ ç $$
$$ È $$

So I am more familiar with what I would think is the standard notation for these operations ($\cup$ , $\cap$) and have never seen this before. Does anyone recognize/regularly use these notations, I'm just curious! Thanks in advance!

Comment: One vote for "never seen it before". Do you have  source?

Comment: @halrankard2 he only place I could find it was a defunct [link](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01J2d-Av4iyWHh5yV9lR6EwIk3Elg%3A1599159240340&source=hp&ei=yDtRX8nUEcbP0PEPwd2bkAc&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAX1FJ2L0lBm8i8FT0S6izo3DIiZKP61Rk&q=intersection+symbol+%C3%A7&oq=int&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgQIIxAnMgQIIxAnMgQIIxAnMgQIABBDMgUIABCRAjIECAAQQzIFCAAQsQMyBAgAEEMyCAguEMcBEK8BMgQIABBDOgoIABCxAxCDARBDUKcBWK8QYJ0WaABwAHgAgAHZBIgBrQiSAQkwLjEuMS41LTGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab), but, in additon, it was on a practice test my friend was taking for a teaching cert exam.

Comment: you know what I'll just start using $ç$ and $È$ for set operations

Comment: That looks like an encoding error...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to me like a Stack Overflow question.

In Unicode, the symbols Ç and È have, respectively, codes [00C7](https://codepoints.net/U+00C7) and [00C8](https://codepoints.net/U+00C8); however, in the [Symbol font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_%28typeface%29), those two same codes correspond to the symbols $\cap$ and $\cup$. Somebody (or something) must have converted the whole text from one font to another while forgetting that some text was in the special (Symbol) font and was not to be changed.

Comment: Ah that actually makes a ton of sense.

Comment: Very happy to give +1 for your 10k. Best year.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks! Have a happy new year too.